# Connect to SQL Server using ZEOS under WINDOWS

Tags: delphi, lazarus, zeos

I want to connect to a SQL Server using ZEOS components under Windows, compiler is LAZARUS.

Here is my function:

```
procedure ConnecttoDatabase(Servername, Databasename: String;
    aConnection: TZConnection); overload;
var
    DatabaseStr: String;
begin
    aConnection.Connected := False;

    aConnection.Database := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=' + Databasename  +'.mdb;Persist Security Info=False';
    aConnection.HostName := Servername;
    aConnection.Protocol := 'ado';

    aConnection.Connected := True;
end;
```

Execute this function I get an "EOLE Exception" error, I need help on the correct connection string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by mirtheil your connection string is wrong.
An easy way to get a good connection string is by using an UDL file.

Simply create a text file with extension `.UDL` and then doubleclick on it from explorer. Now you get a window where you can choose from all installed drivers and choose/enter the values you need.  You can click on `test connection`to see if it works.
Once you get it working there, open this file in notepad and there will be a complete connectionstring.

Comment: connection successfull done - but my "new.udl file" remains empty

Comment: Strange it always gets filled for me. But anyway I am glad it helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string is wrong.  With it, you're trying to use the Jet OLEDB provider.  If you are truly connecting to a Microsoft SQL Server database, you should be using the SQLOLEDB or SQL Native Client to connect.  You can use the MS SQL Server section on [Connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to get a proper connection string.